# Openedge transactions error-handling records are not rolled back in subtransaction

Tags: error-handling, transactions, openedge

I have following code and try to do error-handling. But there is something wrong.

```
    Routine–level throw error.

    PROCEDURE Create-Subrecords :
    For each db-table1 no-lock :
LABEL1:
   For each db-table2 no-lock 
      on error undo, next LABEL1 :
              For each db-table3 no-lock 
        on error undo, throw:
        Create db-table4.
        …..

       End. /*  db-table3 */
       Run proc1.  (Do some database updates on db-table2)

               Catch e as progress.lang.apperror:
             Msg = e:Getmessage(1).  /* save message for later */
             Undo,  next LABEL1.
               End catch.

     End. /*  db-table2 */
    End. /*  db-table1 */
    End PROCEDURE.
```

The problem is that Proc1 returns an error that is catched by the catch statement.
There I want to Undo all the work done  in the transaction started by for each  db-table2.

So I thought that all db-table4 records (created in a subtransaction started by for each db-table3)
must be deleted. => but that is not the case, if I look in the db after my program is done all new db-table4 records are there.

What I am doing wrong? Because I want to roll-back (on error) everything that is started in LABEL1.

Thanks for help

Comment: For everyone's ease: write code that's correct (the command should be ROUTINE-LEVEL ON ERROR UNDO, THROW.) and nicely formatted!

Comment: Found , 
For each db-table2 no-lock 
      on error undo, next LABEL1 : => this one didn't start a transaction.
The first transaction started for each db-table3 and a second transaction was in tjhe run proc1.

I put a transaction-keyword just after for each db-table2 and this works fine.